# Links in spoilers appear faster than the rest of the spoiler contents

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, spoilers

I don't think it is that much important. In a spoiler, the link fades in more quickly than text. This is an example:

> This is a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org) link to demonstrate the effect.

I am using the official build of Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 64-bit.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ5vy.gif) to see a GIF of what is happening.

Comment: No repro, or at least not significant enough, for me on Chrome / Win10

Comment: It fades at the same time but the link appears quicker than remaining text.

Comment: It’s because spoilers use an opacity transition _and_ a color transition from yellow to black. Links don’t seem to use the same color transition.

Comment: Why though? Shouldn't both use the same transition duration?

Comment: @WaisKamal They do use the same transition duration.

Comment: then why don't they fade in at the same time?